# What is the Villain's equity against Hero's cards in this hand?

Tags: equity

In the following hand, please find the Villain's equity of his assumed range. Please share method of calculation and refrain from using equity finding tools.

Hero: Qs 4d
Villain: JJ+

Board: 7c Qc Ks

Would appreciate if step by step calculation is shared for the same. It would make it much easier to understand. Thanks!

Comment: I think the question is slightly too large and complex. Try to change villain's range to one specific hand and you might get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer briefly, and I will assume by JJ+ you mean JJ, QQ, KK, AA. I will also use the 2% 4% rule when counting outs as a shortcut. (google it if you aren't familiar, very useful at the table)

for JJ: Hero is ahead and villain has 2 outs, villain has 6 combinations of JJ with 8% equity

for QQ: Hero is drawing dead, villain has 1 combination of QQ with 100% equity

for KK: Hero is basically drawing dead, only possibility to win is running queens. villain has 6 combinations of KK with ~100% equity

for AA: Hero has 5 outs, (2 Queens, 3 4's) meaning villain has ~80% equity with 6 combinations of AA

***Summary:***

19 total combinations, so just need to average the equity to get total equity.

(6 * 0.08) + 1 + (6 * 1) + (6 * 0.8) = 12.28 / 19 = 64.6% equity with JJ+

Comment: please let me know if there are any errors in my answer, I would appreciate any edits or revisions